# Magento 2 : Custom csp module unknown

Tags: module, magento2

I'm trying to override the csp module of magento but I get an error i don't understand : Unknown module
[here is my module.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/621Ba.png) [registration.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pAme.png) [the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApONC.png)

Answer (score 0):

First try Running, your module will be enabled auto if everything good.

```
php bin/magento s:up
```

Also Check your directory is correct, i see in screenshots app/Code , c needs to be small.

Hope it helps!!